# Difference between 2 regex using egrep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I wanna know what is the difference between:

```
sudo egrep "(08/21/13\-)*(61284103)" /path/to/some_file
sudo egrep "(08/21/13)\-*(61284103)" /path/to/some_file
```

Lets say that for details, the file "some_file" has the next info:

```
08/21/13-01:15:09 foo bar bar and other foo = 11 (61284103)
08/21/13-01:15:11 foo bar number 61284103 another foo
```

The first one returns the both lines, however the second one doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Int the first one, the repeats all of `08/21/13-` zero or more times. So it's looking for something like this:

```
61284103
08/21/13-61284103
08/21/13-08/21/13-61284103
...
```

It can match both lines by matching it `0` times (the first variant).

The second one matches `08/21/13` and then repeats 0 or more hyphens. So it's looking for something like this:

```
08/21/1361284103
08/21/13-61284103
08/21/13--61284103
...
```

However, none of the strings have `08/21/13` separated only by hyphens from `61284103` so neither line matches.

If you wanted to use `*` as a wildcard, use `.*` instead (which repeats an arbitrary character 0 or more times).

Comment: do you have a link to know more about regex in egrep?.

Comment: @ingcarlos not off the top of my head, but for simple matters, [this general-purpose tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) should get you up to speed (and would be enough to understand your problem for instance). For more advanced (flavour-specific) topics, consult the man page, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo egrep "(08/21/13\-)*(61284103)" /path/to/some_file
sudo egrep "(08/21/13)\-*(61284103)" /path/to/some_file
```

The first regex looks for 0 or more matches of the date plus a hyphen, while the second expects a date followed by 0 or more hyphens followed by that number. I would guess that neither regex is what you want to use.

You probably want to use `.*` in the middle of the regex, which allows any text between the date and the number. There's no need for the parentheses or for the `\` to escape `-`.

```
sudo egrep "08/21/13-.*61284103" /path/to/some_file
```

Comment: @John_Kugelman do you have a link to know more about regex in egrep?.

Answer (score 3):

Your first expression "accidentally works". In fact the only thing that is matching is the `61284103` part - the first part is looking for "zero or more instances of" `08/21/13-` to be right before the second part, and it's there (zero times).
In the second part you are looking for the first expression, followed by zero or more instances of `-`, followed by the second expression. That's not going to work - there is "other stuff" in between.

If you actually want lines that match both the first and the second expression, you would need to use:

```
08/21/13.*61284103
```

This matches "exactly the string `08/21/13` followed by "zero or more instances of any character" (`.*`) followed by "exactly the string `61284103`. Which is what you were after.

Comment: Usually you only need to escape it in environments where `/` is used as a delimiter (like Perl, PCRE or JavaScript) - so in egrep you don't.

Comment: @Floris, do you have a link to know more about regex in egrep?